# MySQL subquery result but place criteria on it as well

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to build a query on a heavily normalised database where a number of customer fields and values are held in a different table. This means I have created a subquery to return the value in the custom field:

```
SELECT
LA.ID
,GRP.GROUPNAME
,LP.PRODUCTNAME
,LA.ACCOUNTSTATE
,(LA.FEESBALANCE+LA.PENALTYBALANCE+LA.INTERESTBALANCE+LA.PRINCIPALBALANCE) AS ACCOUNTBALANCE
,AD.POSTCODE
,       (SELECT cv.`VALUE` as vl FROM customfieldvalue cv   JOIN customfield cf on cv.CUSTOMFIELDKEY = cf.ENCODEDKEY    
        WHERE LA.ENCODEDKEY = cv.PARENTKEY AND cf.ID = 'ON_Watch_List_Corporate') as 'watchstatus'
,       (SELECT cv.`VALUE` as vl FROM customfieldvalue cv   JOIN customfield cf on cv.CUSTOMFIELDKEY = cf.ENCODEDKEY    
        WHERE LA.ENCODEDKEY = cv.PARENTKEY AND cf.ID = 'ON_RI-07') as 'PROVISIONAMOUNT'
,       (SELECT cv.`VALUE` as vl FROM customfieldvalue cv   JOIN customfield cf on cv.CUSTOMFIELDKEY = cf.ENCODEDKEY    
        WHERE LA.ENCODEDKEY = cv.PARENTKEY AND cf.ID = 'ON_Security/Collateral_GV') as 'SECUITY/COLLATERAL'
,       (SELECT cv.`VALUE` as vl FROM customfieldvalue cv   JOIN customfield cf on cv.CUSTOMFIELDKEY = cf.ENCODEDKEY    
        WHERE LA.ENCODEDKEY = cv.PARENTKEY AND cf.ID = 'ON_Property_Current_Value') as 'PROPERTYVALUE'


FROM

 LOANACCOUNT LA
,LOANPRODUCT LP
,group GRP
,CUSTOMFIELD CF
,CUSTOMFIELDVALUE CV
,ADDRESS AD
,ACTIVITY AT


WHERE

LA.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = LP.ENCODEDKEY
AND LA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = GRP.ENCODEDKEY
AND GRP.ENCODEDKEY = AD.PARENTKEY
```

However, I also need to include the field PROVISIONAMOUNT in the WHERE criteria - i.e is greater than 0.

Apologies if this is obvious, but I am quite new to SQL and I couldn't find anything that showed if this could be done.

Thank you to anyone who might be able help with this.

Comment: Use a `having` clause instead.  And ,you should show a complete query, even if it is a simplified version of your actual query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your help, but that appeared to make the query run forever without returning any results. I think the issue is partly because i am more used to Oracle and I am combining MySQL and Oracle conventions. I will amend the original question with the full query - it might make more sense then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at your query a while I think it can be rewritten as below, which should be functionally equivalent, but with the added condition of `PROVISIONAMOUNT > 0` . It should be easier to read and also perform better.

In the original version you had included the table `ACTIVITY AT` but I couldn't see that it was being used anywhere so I removed it.

This should work, unless I missed some important detail. Please give it a try, and if is doesn't work I'll remove my answer.

```
SELECT
    LA.ID
    , GRP.GROUPNAME
    , LP.PRODUCTNAME
    , LA.ACCOUNTSTATE
    , (LA.FEESBALANCE+LA.PENALTYBALANCE+LA.INTERESTBALANCE+LA.PRINCIPALBALANCE) AS ACCOUNTBALANCE
    , AD.POSTCODE
    , MAX(CASE WHEN cf.ID = 'ON_Watch_List_Corporate' THEN cv.value END) AS 'watchstatus'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN cf.ID = 'ON_RI-07' THEN cv.value END) AS 'PROVISIONAMOUNT'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN cf.ID = 'ON_Security/Collateral_GV' THEN cv.value END) AS 'SECUITY/COLLATERAL'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN cf.ID = 'ON_Property_Current_Value' THEN cv.value END) AS 'PROPERTYVALUE'

FROM
    LOANACCOUNT LA 
JOIN 
    LOANPRODUCT LP ON LA.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = LP.ENCODEDKEY
JOIN 
    "group" GRP ON LA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = GRP.ENCODEDKEY
JOIN 
    "ADDRESS" AD ON GRP.ENCODEDKEY = AD.PARENTKEY
JOIN 
    customfieldvalue cv ON LA.ENCODEDKEY = cv.PARENTKEY 
JOIN 
    customfield cf ON cv.CUSTOMFIELDKEY = cf.ENCODEDKEY 

GROUP BY
    LA.ID
    , GRP.GROUPNAME
    , LP.PRODUCTNAME
    , LA.ACCOUNTSTATE
    , (LA.FEESBALANCE+LA.PENALTYBALANCE+LA.INTERESTBALANCE+LA.PRINCIPALBALANCE) 
    , AD.POSTCODE
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN cf.ID = 'ON_RI-07' THEN cv.value END) > 0
```

Comment: thank you so much, that seems to be working perfectly. I also understand the changes you have made and the format is much clearer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add the condition in where clause.

```
WHERE
LA.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = LP.ENCODEDKEY
AND LA.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = GRP.ENCODEDKEY
AND GRP.ENCODEDKEY = AD.PARENTKEY
AND PROVISIONAMOUNT > 0
```